# Spring Mvc Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am using **Spring MVC** and i would like when i insert a record into the database via a **POST** when the user is returned to the view i would like to show something like a **Jquery** dialog to the user that says the transaction was successful/display an error message to the use in the dialog.

I implemented the Jquery dialog but for some reason its not working the way i would like it to. I have created it like this :

**jquery**

```
 function ShowDialog() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I attached this to an element event when change:

```
$('#results').change(function()){

            if($('#results').val().length != 0){

                ShowDialog();


            }


        }
```

However when the form loads i get a blank dialog popping up. The element '*results*' is empty and gets set form the server using **model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Updated")** and where the  i created named 'dialog' is located i can see the dialog icon being displayed.

**html**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Server Response">
            <p>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                <label id="results">${results}</label>
            </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your change event change the second line to this:

```
if($('#results').html().length != 0){
```

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only works for form elements (input, select and textarea), whereas `#results` is a normal html element.

Comment: I made that change however i am seeing the dialog icon showing in the page and there isn't any dialog being displayed any suggestions?

Comment: ok i made another change however i am seeing the dialog icon showing in the page where i typed the dialog div after the dialog is displayed the icon doesn't show again any suggestions?